# ngOnInit and MediaChange testing with Karma

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the code in the ngOnInit method. The code watches for change in screen size for a navigation bar to resize down to mobile or to stay as a top bar. I have tried a for about a week and keep getting a slew of different errors when I test. I have left out some code for comp.component.ts as the other code is not necessary for this. I keep getting `subscribe is not a method` or `Can't resolve all parameters for MediaChange: (?, ?, ?, ?)`. Any advice on how I can achieve writing a test for this or any resources you might suggest looking at to help me figure this out.

comp.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-comp',
    templateUrl: './comp.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./comp.component.scss']
})

export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    isOpen: Boolean;
    watcher: Subscription;
    activeMediaQuery = "";
    media: ObservableMedia;

    constructor() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.watcher = this.media.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
            this.activeMediaQuery = change ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})` : '';
            this.isOpen = false;
        });
    }

    navPressed(event, path): void {
        this.navClick.emit(path);
        if ( this.checkSize() ) this.toggle();
    }

    checkSize(): Boolean {
        return this.activeMediaQuery.includes('xs') || this.activeMediaQuery.includes('sm');
    }
}
```

comp.component.spec.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { CompComponent } from './comp.component';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-test-component-wrapper',
    template: '<app-navigation [navItems]="clickables" (navClick)="handleNavClick($event)"></app-navigation>'
})

class TestWrapperComponent {
    clickables = [
        { path: '/login', label: 'Login', onClick() {} }
    ];
}

describe('app testing', () => {
    let component: CompComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestWrapperComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MatButtonModule,
                MatToolbarModule,
                MatIconModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                TestWrapperComponent,
                NavigationComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                ObservableMedia,
                MediaChange,
                Subscription
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestWrapperComponent);
    }));

    it('should create and have Login label', () => {
        // EDIT START
        spyOn(ObservableMedia, 'prototype');
        // EDIT END
        expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
            expect(component.navItems[0].label).toBe('Login');
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT: Added the 'EDIT' comment in the code with the code I have added. I am now getting the `resolve all parameters for MediaChange: (?, ?, ?, ?)` error which I think is forward progress from the subscribe error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

- ObservableMedia from flex-layout needs to be injected into your component to work.  Details [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia)
- You aren't providing MediaChange or Subscription in the original component, so no need to in the TestBed either.

In the stackblitz below I had to make a few assumptions.  Let me know if any of these are wrong, or just go ahead and update the stackblitz:

- In your spec you imported CompComponent, but in comp.component.ts you defined NavigationComponent.  Of the two I chose to use NavigationComponent.
- navClick was missing from your code above, so I assumed it is an @Output from your component (since you emit a path to it).
- navItems was also missing from the code above, but since you are testing it I assumed it was important and guessed it is an input to your component (again, just by the way you were using it).
- You didn't include your template, so I mocked it very simply.
- toggle was called from within navPressed, but didn't exist so I created it as an empty function.

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53024049?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts

**To fix what you had**:  I made the changes above and mocked the ObservableMedia object passed in with the following:

```
let mockFlex = jasmine.createSpyObj({
  subscribe: ({mqAlias: 'xs', mediaQuery: ''}),
  isActive: true,
  });
```

I also changed the providers array to the following:

```
providers: [
    { provide: ObservableMedia, useValue: mockFlex }
]
```

Check the stackblitz for all the details.  As you can see there, the test now passes.

Comment: Sorry I tried to rename a few things and clean up my code for the post but clearly did a terrible job of that, posted it in a rush before I stepped away...lesson learned to not do that again.  Sorry about that. I will dig through your stuff and see if I have any further questions and what not. Thank you for the response I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: this worked like a charm and was very helpful, I was confused about the injection part as it did not have the decorator for Inject. I have some more reading to do on Angular and testing. Thank you so much for the help!